# Program still executes when array length is greater than 5

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I'm working on a small extra credit assignment for class. Basically, the user inputs 5 numbers and then an average is given. I have an if statement to check if the array length is more than 5, and if it is, to shutdown the program.

However, the program seems to execute with the first five given numbers instead of stopping. I'm not sure what I'm overlooking

```
public static double[] getNumbers() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double[] numbers = new double[5];
    System.out.print("Enter integers: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {

        numbers[i] = input.nextDouble();

        if (numbers[i] == 999) {
            System.exit(0);

        }
    }
    return numbers;
}

public static double[] getAverage(double[] numbers) {

    double[] total = new double[1];
    double[] average = new double[1];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        total[0] = total[0] + numbers[i];

    }

    average[0] = total[0] / numbers.length;
    return average;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double[] numbers;
    double average = 0;

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter 5 integers, for example: 10 20 50 84 73");
        numbers = getNumbers();
        if (numbers.length > 5) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        average = numbers[0];
        System.out.println("Average is: " + average);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your array length can never be more than 5

Comment: Do you want to quit accepting numbers if you enter 999?  If so, you're stuck with returning an array of size 5 no matter what.  System.exit(0) is not what you want to do I don't think.  Instead, you could just break out of the loop by putting a break; statement there instead.  The code really wont do anything as it is written.  You'll need to call getNumbers() from your main method.  Have you tried running this yet?

Comment: My bad, I also forgot to mention that I do want it to end if a number entered is 999. I have ran it and it prints out the average for the first five numbers. I see now that the array length can never be more than 5, since I set it to a max of 5.

Answer (score 1):

The array is never bigger than 5, so the program never exits early, no matter how many numbers the user types in.

Because you create the array with a capacity of 5 elements (and because your `for` loop only runs 5 times) your array will never be longer than 5 elements.

```
double[] numbers = new double[5];
//...
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    numbers[i] = input.nextDouble();
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually what **@Hydraxan14** highlighted is correct. Even on entering the 6th value it will still calculate the average of first five integers.

Comment: The asker wants his program to exit if there are more than five numbers, not if there are more than four numbers.  Your program will exit if there are exactly five numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I have optimized your code. On below codes, you can also get the average of sum. `getNumbers()` gets the inputs and returns the array `numbers` and assigns `numbers[]` array on `main` method. then you can check the length of `numbers[]` array, if it is over than 5, `System.exit(0)`, `else`, prints the average number

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessAvagereNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter 5 integers, for example: 10 20 50 84 73");
        double[] numbers = getNumbers();

        if(numbers.length>5){
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Average is: " + getAverage(numbers));
        }          
    }
    private static double[] getNumbers() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double[] numbers = new double[5];
        System.out.print("Enter integers: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            numbers[i] = input.nextDouble();
            if (numbers[i] == 999) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        return numbers;
    }

    private static double getAverage(double[] numbers) {
        double doubleKeeper = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i) {
            doubleKeeper+=numbers[i];
        }
        return doubleKeeper/numbers.length;
    }

}
```